# Better Kitbashing and Asset Management flow, with multiple kits? Organize and browse assets?

Tags: scene, collections, blenderkit

I have 2 [Kitbash3D kits](https://kitbash3d.com/collections/kits), which are huge and contain thousands of assets, plus I'm getting smaller Mech parts kits from an artist from ArtStation.

I want to create a workflow in which I can open the kits and just drag and drop them quickly in Blender to concepting and sketching.

**What am I looking for**

1. A good asset browser, where I could see the 3D models by thumbails, tags and more. Cinema4D has "Content Browser" which is exactly this ([example](https://www.c4dcafe.com/ipb/uploads/monthly_2018_01/c4dbrowserContent.jpg.b09ff4caa5ff238ea5b4e51430b9e969.jpg)).
2. Due to some kits and scenes being very big (for example: https://kitbash3d.com/collections/kits/products/aftermath) I would like to have those scenes open in a separate Blender instance or even open in the "Content Browser" and then just selecting the objects I want and pasting/dragging into my main Blender scene.

**Problems**

1. When I try to open a Kitbash3D file (2.2GB+), it takes minutes upon minutes, every time I open the kit, being discouraging to work (computer specs: 64GB ram, GTX 1060 16GB, i7-7700HQ 2.80GHz). And then, if Blender doesn't crash, the scene is extremely slow, making it impossible to sketch with the kit itself.

As a test, I installed the trial of every major 3D software, and they all managed to load quickly and I could drag and drop individual parts of the kits. But I don't want to use commercial software, I want to use Blender.

2. No way to paste data in Blender, no way to navigate external assets. I know a kind of Asset Browser is coming in 2.93, but it still will take some time and will require me to convert every possible model and asset to the Blender Asset Browser format.

**Questions**

1. How does one work with Kitbashing in Blender, considering the problems I presented?

For example, I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rulrjt25ZQk) which shows how to Kitbash in Blender. But it takes into consideration opening a small kitbash library .blend file and then sketching in the file itself, and not loading additional assets or kits.

2. How does one have an asset library with Blender composing of models, textures and more? And what is your workflow to work with this asset library?

Comment: After writing my question, I reworked the wording of my searches and found a great article: https://artisticrender.com/how-to-do-asset-management-in-blender/ - this is a great beginning!

Comment: This is an external tool, but it's mind blowing, and it has a tight integration with Blender, allowing dragging and dropping https://www.designconnected.com/connecter/ - you still can't simply drag and drop fbx and other formats, but it has a very nice .blend integration. Blender integration video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FjYKQSZXBg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External solutions or addons are the way to go. My method was to experiment all the tools I could find that could deal with problems (1) and (2) described in the topic, with special care in which tool would allow to manage, browse and quickly drop big kitbashing kits into Blender.

The two final solutions that "passed the tests" are:

**Connecter** (https://www.designconnected.com/connecter/)

From their website:

> Free and visual creative assets management for 3d, AEC and design professionals.

Connecter consists of two components:

- A native Desktop software, where you catalog assets of all kinds, by folders, tags and more. It supports all 3D formats, including .blend files natively as well textures, materials, videos, and more.
- A Blender add-on, which allows you to tag objects directly in Blender to be added to Connecter and also to RECEIVE INCOMING DROPS from Connecter, and this is where it shines in terms of asset management for Blender.
- Video showing the process with Blender [on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FjYKQSZXBg).

[image]

**Asset Management** (https://gumroad.com/l/asset_management)

This is a paid Blender addon that adds a "Content Browser" into Blender, for all kinds of assets.

- Its biggest advantage is that it's made for Blender only, so you can expect tight integration with all kinds of Blender objects and data.
- The disadvantage is that you can't manage the assets outside Blender and you can't have other model formats (fbx, etc). You have to convert everything to a friendly Blender format.

Comment: Since nothing else surfaced, I'm choosing my own reply as answer.